# backbone.js collection with overridden toJSON method

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Model which has two properties, which are Collections:

```
MainModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
     colOne:undefined,
     colTwo:undefined
  },

  initialize:function() {
    this.set({colOne:new InnerCollection()});
    this.set({colTwo:new InnerCollection()});
  }
});

InnerCollection= Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
  model: InnerModel, 
});

InnerModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
      ...
});
```

I found that items (`InnerModels`) were not being removed properly from Collections colOne and colTwo. I found a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677815/backbone-js-collection-not-properly-removing-item-in-view) here on Stackoverflow that seemed to explain the cause of the problem and present a solution. I provided an overridden implementation of `toJSON()` on my Model:

```
MainModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
         colOne:undefined,
         colTwo:undefined
      }

      initialize:function() {
        this.set({colOne:new InnerCollection()});
        this.set({colTwo:new InnerCollection()});
      },

      toJSON: function() {
        _.extend(this.attributes, {colOne: this.get('colOne').toJSON()});
        _.extend(this.attributes, {colTwo: this.get('colTwo').toJSON()});
        return this.attributes;
      },
    });
```

**Question #1 -** I'm not really sure why this would solve the problem or why I'm doing it.

**Question #2 -** It causes an error when I try to use the collection `colOne` or `colTwo` in my Views. The stack trace is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object] has no method 'bind'
Backbone.View.extend.initializeinteractiveviews.js:646
Backbone.Viewbackbone.js:1147
childbackbone.js:1392
Backbone.View.extend.renderinteractiveviews.js:441
Backbone.View.extend.renderinteractiveviews.js:619
(anonymous function)interactiveviews.js:766
_.each._.forEachunderscore.js:76
wrapper.(anonymous function)underscore.js:961
Backbone.View.extend.renderinteractiveviews.js:758
Backbone.View.extend.renderinteractiveviews.js:452
Backbone.View.extend.renderinteractiveviews.js:619
(anonymous function)interactiveviews.js:766
_.each._.forEachunderscore.js:76
wrapper.(anonymous function)underscore.js:961
Backbone.View.extend.renderinteractiveviews.js:758
Backbone.View.extend.renderinteractiveviews.js:443
Backbone.View.extend.renderinteractiveviews.js:619
window.AppView.Backbone.View.extend.renderindex.html:73
window.AppView.Backbone.View.extend.initializeindex.html:47
Backbone.Viewbackbone.js:1147
childbackbone.js:1392
(anonymous function)index.html:97
jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery-1.7.2.js:1075
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery-1.7.2.js:1193
jQuery.extend.readyjquery-1.7.2.js:435
DOMContentLoaded
```

`bind` is just the first place where I try and use the collection `colOne`:

```
// this.collection is colOne
this.collection.bind('myEvent', this.myEventHandler);
```

I don't have any syntax errors, so I'm not sure how my toJSON method has broken things.

### Update

This was not a problem with Backbone.js. The problem I was experiencing was down to not unbinding from an event. Consequently, although a particular View was no longer visible once the collection was empty, it was being triggered with an event to add a new item. This s why the count of the collection went up each time I removed an item from a View event.

Comment: _"I fount that items (InnerModels) were not being removed properly from Collections colOne and colTwo"_ **what do you mean with 'being removed properly'?**

Comment: The length of the collection remains unchanged after calling `.remove(myItem)`.

Comment: Edited my original question with the cause of the problem.

Comment: Might be worth answering your question and marking it as accepted. Easier to find for other people running into the same issue.

Comment: Good idea, posted a better explanation as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was not a problem with Backbone.js. The problem I was experiencing was down to not unbinding from an event.

The View which populated the Collection with an Item was no longer visible, but was still bound to a UI event which triggers the addition of an Item to the Collection. The sequence of events was approximately:

```
Event XYZ triggers creation of View2
View2 creates Item and adds to Collection.
```

(`collection.length` now 1).

```
...Item removed from Collection.
```

(`collection.length` now 0).

```
If Collection empty remove `View2`.
View2 removed.
```

At this point if Event XYZ is triggered again, **two View2 instances will be created, therefore 2 items will be added to the collection**. Even if an Item is removed from the Collection, the length is incremented by 1 each time the first Item is removed.

**Summary:** If you do `$(myView).remove()` anywhere in your code and you have used events / binding, check you unbind from the event.